# Error:Execution failed for task gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting following Gradle compilation error:

The execution is failing. Here is the error image :

[image: Error message]

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Answer (score 0):

`multiDexEnabled true`Put multiDexEnabled true under android in gradle file